# Printing from JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, printing

(I rewrite the original question. The problem is the same.)

The above example code do not print the image. It appears in the window but not printed.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

        final JEditorPane ed = new JEditorPane(
                "text/html",
                "<p>Test<br><img  src='http://www.google.es/images/logos/ps_logo2.png'></p>");

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.add(ed);

        JButton b = new JButton("Print");
        f.add(b,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    ed.print();
                } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }
            }
        });

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got this now. The "secret" is to intercept the image loading process and indicate that images should be loaded synchronously.

```
ed.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit() {

            @Override
            public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
                return new HTMLFactory() {

                    @Override
                    public View create(Element elem) {
                        View view = super.create(elem);
                        if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                            ((ImageView) view).setLoadsSynchronously(true);
                        }
                        return view;
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("EditorPane Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            final JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("http://www.google.com");
            editorPane.setEditable(false);

            final HyperlinkListener hyperlinkListener = new ActivatedHyperlinkListener(editorPane);
            editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(hyperlinkListener);

            final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
            frame.add(scrollPane);
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to load: " + e);
        }

        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class ActivatedHyperlinkListener
    implements HyperlinkListener {

    JEditorPane editorPane;

    public ActivatedHyperlinkListener(final JEditorPane editorPane) {
        this.editorPane = editorPane;
    }

    public void hyperlinkUpdate(final HyperlinkEvent hyperlinkEvent) {
        final HyperlinkEvent.EventType type = hyperlinkEvent.getEventType();
        final URL url = hyperlinkEvent.getURL();
        if (type == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED) {
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        }
        else if (type == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            System.out.println("Activated");
            final Document doc = this.editorPane.getDocument();
            try {
                this.editorPane.setPage(url);
                this.editorPane.print();
            }
            catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not really what i'm looking for. I wanted to setup the page content by code (see my edited question).